# PowerShell exception messages, cleaning up extraneous cruft

Tags: powershell, exception

If I catch a basic exception like this

```
try {
   1/0
} catch {
   Write-Host "$($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
}
```

I get neatly formatted terse output that I can use

```
Attempted to divide by zero.
```

However, if attempt to load a module that contains some sort of error

```
try {
   Import-Module -name:$modulePath -disableNameChecking -errorAction:Stop
} catch { 
   Write-Host "$($PSItem.Exception.Message)"
}
```

I get a much less useful mess, with something useful at the end.

```
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: At \\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 3.#\# Dev 3.4.5\Resources\PxFunctions_Tasks.psm1:81 char:33
+ $script:moduleVersion = '3.4.5' junk
+                                 ~~~~
Unexpected token 'junk' in expression or statement.
```

My first question is simple, what is happening here? What actually causes this very different look to the exception message? Is it simply the difference between a logic based exception and one generated by a Cmdlet? Is there some .NET lurking in the explanation?

And second, is there an easy way to clean this up, and ideally get to just that last line `Unexpected token 'junk' in expression or statement.`? Something that would work with ALL exceptions of this (overly verbose) type, not just this one example? Meaning, is that last line available alone as a property somewhere? Because just splitting by return and taking the last seems less than ideal, unless there is some internal rule that Microsoft actually adheres to that the last line in a multi-line exception is always the terse but informative line I want.

EDIT: And then there is the fact that loading a module that contains these lines

```
$script:moduleVersion = '3.4.5' junk
1/0
```

Produces an exception in the first line, but not the second. Sigh.

Comment: What's happening is that the developer thought "It'd probably be a good idea to provide as much PowerShell-specific troubleshooting information as possible when encountering problems with loading script modules" - so they made sure to collect all the parsing errors and put them in the resulting exception's message. Simple as that.

Comment: Can I, with any confidence, assume that this is the only non standard, undocumented "I just felt like it" I have to deal with here? I REALLY wish Microsoft had some, erm, standards once in a while. 

Comment: I'm not really sure how to respond to this - Microsoft never promised "we only throw single-line exceptions", and I'm a little baffled you're upset about getting better contextual details in your error messages. I guess the answer is "no, that's a false assumption"

Comment: I guess what I expect from MS is "consistency". But that is not the Microsoft way, and if this issue is limited to module load I should be able to work around it. Thanks for pointing me down the right path in any case.